# Passing variable to setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval

Been trying to do this over and over again and but my variable just outputs undefined in the div "current". So I want to pass a "changing" variable from "function one" to "function two". Tried to set up a simple example :)

```
<div id="current"></div>

<script> 
id = 0;
setInterval(function one(){
id++;
name = 'id' + id;
},1000);


setInterval(function two(){

    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=name; //outputs undefined

},10);
</script>
```

Comment: `name` is a local function of `one()`. Declare it as global (like `id`)

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/tAZfH/

Comment: Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/74EPH/ Except that the second function runs before `name` has been assigned a value by the first function, which means that it is displaying the value of the `window.name` property (which you'll notice in jsfiddle is actually "result"). @Reeno - `name` is global.

Comment: @Reeno It actually is not. The `var` is missing in front of it, which brings it to the global scope, which both functions share.

Comment: If I don't put var infront, does it become global then? @Sirko

Comment: it becomes global but its a good practise to explicitly define as a global and use `var` anyway :)

Comment: @PeterP If you put a `var` in front of it, it is bound to the current scope. If you don't do this, the interpreter searches all scopes up to the global scope to find the variable. If it doesn't find it anywhere, it creates a new global variable of that name.

Comment: Well, works now when I took the "var" away from real code :P THanks @Sirko

Comment: moreover, why dont you invoke a method `two()` in your `one()` instead of your current construction with a 2nd interval?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pPk4y/ it works? click run on link. as Sirko said as there is no var in front of 'name' it becomes a global variable

```
id = 0;
setInterval(function one(){
id++;
name = 'id' + id;
},1000);


setInterval(function two(){

    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=name; //outputs undefined

 },10);
```

Comment: Yes it works! saw that I had "var" infront of "name" in real code! :) @Dere_2929